# How to get a value from a specific site using xpath and store it in an array? (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, html, http, xpath

I would like to ask what is the problem with my code. I want to get the results from the html page and store the value in a string or later on an array.... Thanks

> 09-05 16:36:41.221: I/test(22697): plan failed 1org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: attr value delimiter missing! (position:START_TAG @1:166 in java.io.StringReader@4061bc98) 
>   09-05 16:36:41.221: I/test(22697): plan failed 1a @1:166 in java.io.StringReader@4061bc98) 
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:151)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at com.asiatype.boracay.CurrencyActivity$DownloadData.doInBackground(CurrencyActivity.java:194)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at com.asiatype.boracay.CurrencyActivity$DownloadData.doInBackground(CurrencyActivity.java:1)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   09-05 16:36:41.231: W/System.err(22697):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)

```
            String s,link;
        String theResult = "";
        link="http://www.bsp.gov.ph/statistics/sdds/exchrate.htm";
        Document doc;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            htmlSource = str.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                      .newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(htmlSource)));
            XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                      .newXPath().compile("//div/table/tbody/tr[child::td[contains(text(),\"USD\")]]/td[15]");
                    htmlResult = (String) xpath.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 1"+e1);
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 1a "+ htmlSource);
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 1a "+ htmlResult);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 2");

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 3");

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("test", "plan failed 4");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to extract data from http://www.bsp.gov.ph/statistics/sdds/exchrate.htm ?

Comment: yes.. i just want to get the value from a table using xpath.... i'm new to it...

Answer (score 1):

The [source](http://www.bsp.gov.ph/statistics/sdds/exchrate.htm)  HTML file you are using as input is not well formed XML which is why the `SAXParseException` is being thrown - letting you know that an XML attribute's value delimiter is missing.

HTML and XML are very different. For example, HTML can have missing or non-matching end tags, and unquoted attribute values, whereas XML does not allow that. It is strongly discouraged to **not** attempt to parse HTML as XML for this reason. The parsing just cannot cater for all the inconsistencies that HTML allows.

There are a few alternative approaches to solve this:

1. From [Reading HTML file to DOM tree using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java) - use [Neko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) to attempt to make the HTML valid XML, which would enable you to keep the existing SAXParser code you have to find the date
2. From same question above - use [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to parse the HTML into a DOM tree and find your data using DOM methods instead. See [xml dom parser in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481960/xml-dom-parser-in-java) for some Java DOM parsers