# how to change data in Xml using java?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

suppose i have an xml as follows :

```
<alerts>
    <fullName>email_alert_campaign</fullName>
    <description>email alert campaign</description>
    <recipients>
        <recipient>abc_puv@xyz.com</recipient>
        <type>user</type>
    </recipients>
    <senderType>CurrentUser</senderType>
</alerts>
<tasks>
    <fullName>Task_on_completing_a_campaign</fullName>
    <assignedTo>abc_puv@xyz.com</assignedTo>
    <subject>Task on completing a campaign</subject>
</tasks>
```

in a xml file i have data  like "abc_puv@xyz.com" need to replace with "XYZ" using java i have to write a java code where it can search in 100's of xml's and replace with data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code 
test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<alerts>
    <fullName>email_alert_campaign</fullName>
    <description>email alert campaign</description>
    <recipients>
        <recipient>abc_puv@xyz.com</recipient>
        <type>user</type>
    </recipients>
    <senderType>CurrentUser</senderType>
</alerts>
<tasks>
    <fullName>Task_on_completing_a_campaign</fullName>
    <assignedTo>abc_puv@xyz.com</assignedTo>
    <subject>Task on completing a campaign</subject>
</tasks>
</root>

public class XMLParsing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
        File fXmlFile = new File("D:/test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        // optional, but recommended
        // read this -
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); 
        XPathExpression expr = xpath
                .compile("//assignedTo");
        Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + node.getTextContent());
        node.setTextContent("abc_puv@efg.com");

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to persist the changed data in Xml ? unable to save the changed data in xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are (as per the [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) tag) looking to do this with JAXB the steps are the following:

1. Map your object model to the XML structure using the standard JAXB annotations where necessary.
2. Unmarshal the XML into your object model.
3. Update the value if it needs changing.
4. If the model changed marshal it back to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Write an XSLT transformation, for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="recipient|assignedTo">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'abc_puv@xyz.com', 'XYZ')"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then (e.g. by using the JAXP API) apply this transformation to each of your XML documents.