# How to get data from XML into Java

Tags: java, xml

I would like to know how to get data from XML file into my java code. For this i would be creating my XML files and and then will be writing a java code. Then i'll try to fetch data from XML to java. For this some mapping has to be done in my java code or i have to use some java API. Kindly help with your knowledge or provide me some link for studying!

Comment: And what stops you to use some kind of database for that purpose? You could use for example Derby embedded database.

Answer (score 3):

You can read XML in as a String and [parse it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) using a built in SAX or DOM parser.

You can use [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) to map XML directly into your objects.

Your choice.  But you need to do some Googling and study.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOM XML Parser (JAXP). The following example is taken from mkyong

```
<company>
<staff id="1001">
    <firstname>yong</firstname>
    <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <salary>100000</salary>
</staff>
<staff id="2001">
    <firstname>low</firstname>
    <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
    <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
    <salary>200000</salary>
</staff>
</company>
```

The java code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadXMLFile {

   public static void main(String argv[]) {

       try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile); 
        //optional, but recommended
        //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 
        System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Jaxb2Marshaller` from Spring. First you need to create the `Jaxb2Marshaller` bean in your Spring context specifying the classes to be bound for the marshaller and the schemas where the XML is defined:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.Employee</value>
            <value>com.example.Department</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:schemas/schema.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In your code, get the string XML and use the marshaller to unmarshal the object. For example:

```
@Autowire
private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;
```

...

```
final Employee employee = (Employee) marshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```