# Parsing XML file from resources

Tags: java, android, xml, exception

I am attempting to parse an XML file from Resources. After I have the file parsed I intend to perform some XPATH functions on it.

The code I have is :

```
Resources res = getResources();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
Document doc = null;
XPathExpression expr = null;

    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        doc = builder.parse(res.getResourceName(R.xml.cdatest01));
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When debugging the code throws an IOException error in the parse statement. The logcat shows the error as

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: com.apps4care.mycarerecord
```

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong...

Comment: That was a typo in me writing the question - corrected above now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to pass a full resource name from `Resources.getResourceName` to `DocumentBuilder.parse` which expects a URI string.  These are not the same thing.

This is why you get a MalformedURLException

There's a number of ways you could do this differently including:

1. Call the variant of `DocumentBuilder.parse` which takes an InputStream and use `res.openRawResource` instead.   That's probably the smaller change.
2. Use `Resources.getXml` to get back an XML pull parser and use that instead of using the DOM API to parse the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
InputStream fIn = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hot);
Document doc=builder.parse(fIn);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use my running code....

```
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("/root/Desktop/staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        // optional, but recommended
        // read this -
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Staff id : "
                        + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("First Name : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname")
                                .item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Last Name : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Nick Name : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Salary : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: up to the point where my code throws an exception the code is the same - apart from my problem area which is getting the XML from a resource file.