# Comparing of two XML DOC is getting fail because docs is comimg from two source

Tags: java, xml

I have converted a string to an XML document using the code below:

```
String xmlStr = "<msg><uuid>12345</uuid></msg>"
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
try {
  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
  return doc;
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Then I converted an XML file to a document with the following:

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/xmlForJunitTest.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document expectedDoc = db.parse(file);
```

Finally I compare the two documents:

```
Document actualDoc = XmlUtils.convertStringToDocument(xmlString);
Diff myDiff = new Diff(expectedDoc, actualDoc);
assert (myDiff.similar());
```

This test passes using an XML file (xmlForJunitTest.xml) formatted like so:

```
<msg><uuid>12345</uuid></msg>
```

And it fails with this:

```
<msg>
   <uuid>12345</uuid>
</msg>
```

Please you can suggest why this failure occurs, and what the solution is?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 0):

The assertion fails because one document includes whitespace, and the other doesn't. I believe you need to look at the `normalizeWhitespace` flag in `XmlUnit` (assuming that's what you're using).