# Android XML: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , DOMParser

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I have a problem to using a DOMParserXML to take data stored in a xml file called: "infofermata.xml" and placed this path: "xml/infofermata.xml". 
The first problem that I found is: `"2246-2246/com.example.giacomob.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /xml\infofermata.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"`
 The class that will read in this XML file is:

```
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.util.Log;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class ReadXMLFile {

     public ReadXMLFile() {

        try {
            Log.i("MyActivity", "casa");
            String filePath = "xml\\infofermata.xml";
            File fXmlFile = new File(filePath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //optional, but recommended
            //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fermata");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
               // Log.i("MyActivity", "casa");

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                   // System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));

                   // String stringidfermata = "Id Fermata : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent()"";

                   // Log.i("MyActivity", "\"Id Fermata : \" + eElement.getElementsByTagName(\"idfermata\").item(0).getTextContent()");
                    System.out.println("Id Fermata : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Naziome : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nazione").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Paese : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("paese").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Via : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("via").item(0).getTextContent());

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I supposed that the error is in: " String filePath = "xml\infofermata.xml";", ma that path aren't wrong...please, help me!!

This is my XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fermata>
    <idfermata>1</idfermata>
    <nazione>Italia</nazione>
    <paese>Lecce</paese>
    <via>Viale Grassi</via>
</fermata>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: change the file path.

String filePath = "xml/infofermata.xml";

Comment: Thanks @Rubanraj, but I had already tried ..but doesn't work! for information I use Android Developer on WIndows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giacomo, the res folder is reserved for application resources, then to read a file in it you have to use the getResources() method, and then the getXml(). This [example](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html) is a little bit outdated, but I believe can help you.
If you want to use the DocumentBuilderFactory and the other java class for DOM, I suggest you to put your xml in the 'assets' folder of your app, the you get the InputStream using:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("infofermata.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
[...]
is.close();
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks @mimmo grottoli.. but you're italian? Sei italiano? così parliamo nella nostra lingua madre magari, così forse capisco un po' meglio..

Comment: I'd like but I think it's not possibile :)

Comment: okok..:) This is my first experience in Android. From your answer I understand that I have to create a new directory (in main) called "assets" and I put in this directory the xml file, true?

Comment: Yes, AndroidStudio should automaticcaly apply a custom icon to that folder (the same of the res folder)

Comment: nothing... the same error... The sintax it's true?
String filePath = "assets/infofermata.xml";
            File fXmlFile = new File(filePath);

Comment: No! You don't need to open a file. Look at the code I wrote: `AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); ...` That is the way to get a file from assets folder.

Comment: ahhhhh.. ok, but now the method "getAssets();" is red: "Cannot resolve method 'getAssets()'"

Comment: Ok - of course you need a Context. If you're launching the method to read the file from an Activity, pass the reference to that Activity. `public static void readXmlFile(Context context) { AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets(); ...}` and from Activity `ReadXMLFile.readXmlFile(this);`

Comment: ok, in Main activity i have to delete:    ReadXMLFile a = new ReadXMLFile();? and i have to add  ReadXMLFile.readXmlFile(this);?

Comment: This is what I would do, make the readXmlFile a static method.

Comment: ok, I have substituted   ReadXMLFile a = new ReadXMLFile(); in    ReadXMLFile.ReadXMLFile(this);
the class ReadXMLFIle will appear:
public class ReadXMLFile {

     public static void readXMLFile(Context context) {

        try {
            Log.i("MyActivity", "casa");

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("infofermata.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
ecc ecc..
but geaAssest is red yet...cannot resolve metod getAssests...

Comment: It Work!! Thanks thanks!! You're the best!!!! :) there is a way to vote your answer ?