# XML file is not read completely

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, parsing

I created an XML file by using following code in Java:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// root elements
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

// staff elements
Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
rootElement.appendChild(staff);

// set attribute to staff element
Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
attr.setValue("1");
staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

// shorten way
// staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

// firstname elements
Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
staff.appendChild(firstname);

// lastname elements
Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
staff.appendChild(lastname);

// nickname elements
Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
staff.appendChild(nickname);

// salary elements
Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
staff.appendChild(salary);

// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\file.xml"));

// Output to console for testing
// StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

transformer.transform(source, result);

System.out.println("File saved!");
```

and then I wanted to read this file by using following code:

```
public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("D:\\file.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    //optional, but recommended
    //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
            System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

but in the output just is written following text:

```
> Root element :company
----------------------------
```

and other fields are not written in the out put, Whereas it seems that both writer and reader code are match to each other.
What should be modified in reader code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the statement as below

```
   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Staff");
```

in the argument, you passed as "staff".