# intent - Error:(67, 53) error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, this, domparser

I have a class called `ReadXMLFile.java` that get a parsing on a XML file called `infofermata.xml`. Using the `DOMParser`, it works. 
My app have a `Button` in the `MainActivity` that link in another activity (carry on `ReadXMFile` using `<ReadXMLFile.readXMLFile(this);>`) called "Page1". Now I would to switch data withdrawn from my `DOMParser` (in `ReadXMLFile.java`) in Page1, for visualize that data (stored into `infofermata.xml`).

For this reason I suppose to use an `Intent`, I write this rows in `ReadXMLFile.java` after the parsing:

```
String testo1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent();
Intent nuovaPagina = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
nuovaPagina.putExtra("NomeDati1", testo1);
```

["testo1" contains the string that I would switch in "Page1"]

But there are an error: `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

This is `ReadXMLFile` code:

```
/**
 * Created by Giacomo B on 30/07/2015.
 */
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class ReadXMLFile {

     public static void readXMLFile(Context context) {

        try {
          //  Log.i("MyActivity", "casa");

            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("infofermata.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

           // String filePath = "assets/infofermata.xml";
            //File fXmlFile = new File(filePath);
            //DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            //DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //optional, but recommended
            //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fermata");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
               // Log.i("MyActivity", "casa");

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                   // System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));

                   // String stringidfermata = "Id Fermata : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent()"";

                   // Log.i("MyActivity", "\"Id Fermata : \" + eElement.getElementsByTagName(\"idfermata\").item(0).getTextContent()");
                    System.out.println("Id Fermata : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent());
                    String testo1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("idfermata").item(0).getTextContent();
                    Intent nuovaPagina = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
                    nuovaPagina.putExtra("NomeDati1", testo1);

                    System.out.println(testo1); //provo per vedere se stampa quello che ho messo nella variabile "testo1"
                    System.out.println("Naziome : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nazione").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Paese : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("paese").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Via : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("via").item(0).getTextContent());


                }

                is.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This is `infofermata.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fermata>
    <idfermata>1</idfermata>
    <nazione>Italia</nazione>
    <paese>Lecce</paese>
    <via>Viale Grassi</via>
</fermata>
```

This is `MainActivity.java` code:

```
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ReadXMLFile.readXMLFile(this);
        Button b_load=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent openPage1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page1.class);
                startActivity(openPage1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What I can do now? Please, help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the enclosing instance of the class. Static methods are not members of an instance of the class; they are members of the Class object itself, so they do not have an enclosing instance to reference.

You are already passing in a Context to this method, so just use that instead of `this`.

Comment: Can you write an example row for me, Please? I'm still a beginner :) thanks :)

Comment: @GiacomoBrunetta `new Intent(context, Page1.class);`