# How to get an XML node values using Java?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xpath, domxpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<events>
<event>
<id>1234567</id>
<Assets>
<Asset>
<UploadURL>
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-construct-a-file-path-in-java/
</UploadURL>
<FTP>
<RequestDT>2016-02-29 12:36:52 -0500</RequestDT>
<ResponseDT>2016-02-29 12:36:58 -0500</ResponseDT>
</FTP>
<URL>
<Value>
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/
</Value>
</URL>
</Asset>
</Assets>
</event>
</events>
```

Java file:

```
package src;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import java.io.File;

    public class ReadXMLFile {
      public static void main(String argv[]) {
     try {
    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/mykong/Documents/staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    //optional, but recommended
        //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("UploadURL").item(0).getTextContent());
    //          System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
    //          System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
    //          System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
     }
```

I am not getting any output for this. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I do not see a tag named staff. doc.getElementsByTagName("event")?

Comment: "I am not getting any output for this" - also no exceptions? Do you get the output for the root element?

Comment: @– Eritrean ...thanks it worked ..issue was with  I do not see a tag named staff. doc.getElementsByTagName("event")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the xml file don't have this node.

```
  doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
```