# Read and print out XML file to console

Tags: java, xml

I need to printout some attributes from an xml file i've created.

So far i am inspired by MKyoung and have made some changes in his. But i cant get the xml attributes. I want to print out the name in the "" and the score.

```xml
    <score name="Rasmus" score="10000"/>
```

My code for getting it is:

```java
public void readXMLFile() {
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("highscore.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        //optional, but recommended
        //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Highscore");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element : " + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getAttribute("score"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my xml file named highscore.xml contains this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Highscore>
  <score name="Rasmus" score="10000"/>
  <score name="Søren" score="6000"/>
  <score name="Niclas" score="5000"/>
</Highscore>
```

Comment: you have to iterate through the next level of nodes. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47248264/5832518)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code by adding two lines. Check below. Basically, you have to iterate through next level of nodes.

**code:**

```java
public void readXMLFile() {
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("highscore.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Highscore");
        Node child = nList.item(0);
        NodeList nL = child.getChildNodes();    
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        int i = 1;
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nL.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nL.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println(i + "," + eElement.getAttribute("name") + "," + eElement.getAttribute("score"));
                i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Root element : Highscore
----------------------------
1,Rasmus,10000
2,Søren,6000
3,Niclas,5000
```

Comment: Ye exactly like this! And if i only want to count on the scores and not the #text? Im trying to make a highscore list count so it says 1. "Name"    "Score" and next is 2. "Name"   "Score"? Cause if i use the counter temp then it counts the #text also

Comment: @NiclasJohansen, Please check the updated answer and output. I have used `i` as the counter.

Comment: Thank u very much!

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use open source libaries like simple-xml.

```
private Serializer serializer = new Persister();

// Reading
(YOUROBJECT) serializer.read(YOUROBJECT.class, new File(path));
// Writing
serializer.write(YOUROBJECT, file);
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simpleframework/simple-xml/2.7.1

Comment: But will this make me able to print out the attribute score to the console?