# how to get tag name at xml

Tags: java, xml

[image]

above is my XMl...

how to get the name of the element tag like `ReportDate`, `PeriodEndingDate`, `FileDate` and so on?

```
List<String> stkCompFinaciallist = new ArrayList<String>();

        File fXmlFile = new File(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        // optional, but recommended
        // read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("BalanceSheetEntity");
        out.println("length=" + nList.getLength());

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            //out.println("node name:"+ nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


            if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").getLength() > 0) {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    out.println("ReportDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                } else {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add("");
                }

                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").getLength() > 0) {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    out.println("PeriodEndingDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());



                } else {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add("");
                }

                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("FileDate").getLength() > 0) {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Start").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    out.println("FileDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("FileDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                } else {
                    stkCompFinaciallist.add("");
                }
```

Above Coding can get the Node Value. 
Cause the tag name is more than 200 tag, so i plan get the tag name first just using for loop to get the value.
and this tag also have another purpose.

please kindly advice how to get the tag name? i only need the tag name of `BalansheetEntity`.

Thanks and best regards
Sharon

Comment: Did you consider using JAXB ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

Answer (score 1):

can you use Xpath here. if your XML structure always contain tag - BalansheetEntity you can use XPAth to get all child nodes of BalansheetEntity  tag.

Also it is better to use XSD to validate xml structure.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: Thanks...I get the answer