# How to get multiple value tag

Tags: java, xml

below is the sample my xml

```
<SegmentSheetEntityList> 
<SegmentSheetEntity> 
  <ReportDate>2016-12-31</ReportDate> 
  <PeriodEndingDate>2016-12-31</PeriodEndingDate> 
  <FileDate>2017-03-29</FileDate> 
  <StatementType>Annual</StatementType> 
  <DataType>A</DataType> 
  <CurrencyId>USD</CurrencyId> 
  <FiscalYearEnd>12</FiscalYearEnd> 
  <AccessionNumber>0001144204-17-017344</AccessionNumber> 
  <FormType>10-K</FormType> 
  <SegmentDetailEntityList> 
    <SegmentDetailEntity> 
      <SegmentType>Business</SegmentType> 
      <SegmentName>Single segment</SegmentName> 
      <IsPrimarySegment>true</IsPrimarySegment> 
      <ValueType>Reported</ValueType> 
      <IsSubTotal>0</IsSubTotal> 
      <SegmentReportDetailEntityList> 
        <SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
          <DataName>Operating Revenue</DataName> 
          <DataValue>12855811.000000</DataValue> 
          <CalculationIndicator>false</CalculationIndicator> 
        </SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
      </SegmentReportDetailEntityList> 
    </SegmentDetailEntity> 
    <SegmentDetailEntity> 
      <SegmentType>Geographic</SegmentType> 
      <SegmentName>Europe</SegmentName> 
      <IsPrimarySegment>true</IsPrimarySegment> 
      <RegionName>Europe</RegionName> 
      <ValueType>Reported</ValueType> 
      <IsSubTotal>0</IsSubTotal> 
      <SegmentReportDetailEntityList> 
        <SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
          <DataName>Total Assets</DataName> 
          <DataValue>9766602.000000</DataValue> 
          <CalculationIndicator>false</CalculationIndicator> 
        </SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
        <SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
          <DataName>Operating Revenue</DataName> 
          <DataValue>11953015.000000</DataValue> 
          <CalculationIndicator>false</CalculationIndicator> 
        </SegmentReportDetailEntity> 
      </SegmentReportDetailEntityList> 
    </SegmentDetailEntity>
```

after i code, for SegmentReportDetailEntityList, DataName, Data Value always get the first ones only, if they have 2nd or so on at SegmentReportDetailEntity, it can't get it.

it suppose get this answer

```
  ReportDate : 2016-12-31
 PeriodEndingDate : 2016-12-31
 FileDate : 2017-03-29
 StatementType : Annual
 DataType : A
 Interim : USD
 FiscalYearEnd : 12
 AccessionNumber : 0001144204-17-017344
 SegmentType : Business
 SegmentName : Single segment
 IsPrimarySegment : true
 ValueType : Reported
 IsSubTotal : 0
 DataName : Operating Revenue
 DataValue : 12855811.000000
 CalculationIndicator : false

ReportDate : 2016-12-31
PeriodEndingDate : 2016-12-31
FileDate : 2017-03-29
StatementType : Annual
DataType : A
Interim : USD
FiscalYearEnd : 12
AccessionNumber : 0001144204-17-017344
SegmentType : Geographic
SegmentName : Europe
IsPrimarySegment : true
ValueType : Reported
RegionName : Europe
IsSubTotal : 0
DataName : Total Assets
DataValue : 9766602.000000
CalculationIndicator : false

ReportDate : 2016-12-31
PeriodEndingDate : 2016-12-31
FileDate : 2017-03-29
StatementType : Annual
DataType : A
Interim : USD
FiscalYearEnd : 12
AccessionNumber : 0001144204-17-017344
SegmentType : Geographic
SegmentName : Europe
IsPrimarySegment : true
ValueType : Reported
RegionName : Europe
IsSubTotal : 0
DataName : Operating Revenue
DataValue : 11953015.000000
CalculationIndicator : false
```

for others tag is no problem.

below is my coding:

```
public void processRawXML(String filename, String exchange, String symbol) throws Exception {
    try {

        List<String> segSheetlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        File fXmlFile = new File(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        // optional, but recommended
        // read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SegmentSheetEntityList");
        out.println("node name=" + doc.getDocumentElement().getTagName());

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                // out.println("debug1 : " + eElement.getTextContent());

                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("SegmentDetailEntityList").getLength() > 0) {
                    out.println("\nCurrent Element length eelement Detail:" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SegmentDetailEntityList").getLength());

                    NodeList ndetailList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SegmentDetailEntityList").item(0).getChildNodes();
                    for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < ndetailList.getLength(); temp1++) {

                        Node ndetailNode = ndetailList.item(temp1);

                        out.println("\nCurrent Element balancesheet:" + ndetailNode.getNodeName());

                        if (ndetailNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                            Element eElement1 = (Element) ndetailNode;

                            if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentReportDetailEntity").getLength() > 0) {

                                NodeList nreportList = eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentReportDetailEntityList");
                                for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nreportList.getLength(); temp2++) {
                                    Node nrptNode = nreportList.item(temp2);

                                    if (nrptNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                        Element eElement2 = (Element) nrptNode;

                                    segSheetlist.add(exchange);
                                    segSheetlist.add(symbol);
                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("ReportDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReportDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("PeriodEndingDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("PeriodEndingDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }
                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("FileDate").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("FileDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("FileDate : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("FileDate").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("StatementType").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("StatementType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("StatementType : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("StatementType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }
                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("DataType").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("DataType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("DataType : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("DataType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }
                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("Interim").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Interim").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("Interim : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Interim").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyId").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyId").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("Interim : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyId").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("FiscalYearEnd").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("FiscalYearEnd").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("FiscalYearEnd : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("FiscalYearEnd").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("AccessionNumber").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("AccessionNumber").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("AccessionNumber : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("AccessionNumber").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentType").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("SegmentType : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentName").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("SegmentName : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsPrimarySegment").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsPrimarySegment").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("IsPrimarySegment : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsPrimarySegment").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("ValueType").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("ValueType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("ValueType : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("ValueType").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("RegionName").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("RegionName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("RegionName : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("RegionName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsSubTotal").getLength() > 0) {
                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsSubTotal").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        out.println("IsSubTotal : " + eElement1.getElementsByTagName("IsSubTotal").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                    } else {
                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                    }

                                    
                                        if (eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataName").getLength() > 0) {
                                            segSheetlist.add(eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                            out.println("DataName : " + eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        } else {
                                            segSheetlist.add("");
                                        }

                                        if (eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").getLength() > 0) {
                                            segSheetlist.add(eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                            out.println("DataValue : " + eElement2.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        } else {
                                            segSheetlist.add("");
                                        }

                                        if (eElement2.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").getLength() > 0) {
                                            segSheetlist.add(eElement2.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                            out.println("CalculationIndicator : " + eElement2.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        } else {
                                            segSheetlist.add("");
                                        }
                                        
                                        segSheetlist.clear();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // doData2DB(segSheetlist);
                        
                        }
                    }

                }

                segSheetlist.clear();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(expMsg + e.getMessage() + " at processRawXML");
        StackTraceElement[] st = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            out.println(st[i].toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `eElement1.getChildNodes()` instead of `doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SegmentReportDetailEntityList").item(0).getChildNodes()`.

Here is the updated code which is returning all the `SegmentReportDetailEntity` object values.

```
public static void processRawXML(String filename, String exchange, String symbol) throws Exception {
    try {

        List<String> segSheetlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        File fXmlFile = new File(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("segmentsheetentity");
        System.out.println("node name=" + doc.getDocumentElement().getTagName());

        System.out.println("node length=" + nList.getLength());

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("SegmentDetailEntityList").getLength() > 0) {

                    NodeList ndetailList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SegmentDetailEntityList").item(0).getChildNodes();
                    if(ndetailList.getLength()>0){
                        for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < ndetailList.getLength(); temp1++) {

                            Node ndetailNode = ndetailList.item(temp1);


                              if(ndetailNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("SegmentDetailEntity")){

                                  Element eElement1 = (Element) ndetailNode;
                                  if (eElement1.getElementsByTagName("SegmentReportDetailEntityList").getLength() > 0){

                                      NodeList nSegmentReportDetailEntityList = eElement1.getChildNodes();
                                       if(nSegmentReportDetailEntityList.getLength()>0){
                                           for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nSegmentReportDetailEntityList.getLength(); temp2++){
                                               Node nreportdetailNode = nSegmentReportDetailEntityList.item(temp2);
                                               if(nreportdetailNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("SegmentReportDetailEntityList")){
                                               System.out.println("\nCurrent Element balancesheet:" + nreportdetailNode.getNodeName());
                                               Element eElement2 = (Element) nreportdetailNode;
                                               NodeList nSegmentReportDetailEntity = eElement2.getChildNodes();
                                                for(int temp3=0;temp3<nSegmentReportDetailEntity.getLength();temp3++){
                                                    Node nreportNode = nSegmentReportDetailEntity.item(temp3);
                                                    if(nreportNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("SegmentReportDetailEntity")){
                                                    Element eElement3 = (Element) nreportNode;
                                                     System.out.println("\nCurrent t##############:" + nreportNode.getNodeName());
                                                     if (eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataName").getLength() > 0) {
                                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                        System.out.println("DataName : " + eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataName").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                    } else {
                                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                                    }
                                                     if (eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").getLength() > 0) {
                                                            segSheetlist.add(eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                            System.out.println("DataValue : " + eElement3.getElementsByTagName("DataValue").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                        } else {
                                                            segSheetlist.add("");
                                                        }
                                                     if (eElement3.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").getLength() > 0) {
                                                        segSheetlist.add(eElement3.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                        System.out.println("CalculationIndicator : " + eElement3.getElementsByTagName("CalculationIndicator").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                                    } else {
                                                        segSheetlist.add("");
                                                    }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
                                  }
                              }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " at processRawXML");
        StackTraceElement[] st = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(st[i].toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I just printed `SegmentReportDetailEntity` values. If you need will send complete code displaying all the elements.

Comment: Thank you very much...i get the answer