# How to read a particular column of data in Excel XML spreadsheet(.XML)?

Tags: java, xml

I am doing selenium Java automation.

In the application there is a feature to upload Project data through Excel XML spreadsheet(2003) (saved in .XML format).
Once I uploaded the data I need to verify the uploaded data with the data in the spreadsheet

eg. Project ID.

So that I need to read Project ID column in XML spreadsheet.
Can anyone tell me how to access and read such file using selenium Java.

Below is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   </DocumentProperties>
   <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <AllowPNG />
   </OfficeDocumentSettings>
   <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <WindowHeight>7545</WindowHeight>
      <WindowWidth>20490</WindowWidth>
      <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
      <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
      <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
      <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
   </ExcelWorkbook>
   <Styles>
      <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
         <Borders />
         <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" />
         <Interior />
         <NumberFormat />
         <Protection />
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s62">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
         <Borders />
         <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" />
         <Interior />
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="@" />
         <Protection />
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s65">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
         <Borders>
            <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
         </Borders>
         <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1" />
         <Interior ss:Color="#75923C" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
         <NumberFormat />
         <Protection />
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s66">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
         <Borders>
            <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
            <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
         </Borders>
         <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1" />
         <Interior ss:Color="#333399" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
         <NumberFormat />
         <Protection />
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s81">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Top" />
      </Style>
   </Styles>
   <Worksheet ss:Name="Submit Project">
      <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="5" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
         <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="110.25" />
         <Column ss:Width="110.25" />
         <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="110.25" ss:Span="2" />
         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s65">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Fields</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Spreadsheet Key*</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Project</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Worker</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Project ID</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.4375">
            <Cell ss:Index="2">
               <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s81">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Project.2018931</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.4375">
            <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s81" />
         </Row>
         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.4375">
            <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s81" />
         </Row>
         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.4375">
            <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s81" />
         </Row>
      </Table>
      <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
         <Unsynced />
         <Selected />
         <LeftColumnVisible>1</LeftColumnVisible>
         <Panes>
            <Pane>
               <Number>3</Number>
               <ActiveRow>7</ActiveRow>
               <ActiveCol>2</ActiveCol>
            </Pane>
         </Panes>
         <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
         <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
      </WorksheetOptions>
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Removed selenium and UI related tags since they arent required here and added XML.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can use `DocumentBuilderFactory, DocumentBuilder,XpathFactory and Xpath` to read an XML file. Following example has been taken from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

We can write the following code to do so:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

try {

File fXmlFile = new File("staff.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

//optional, but recommended
//read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

System.out.println("----------------------------");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
   }
```

The output of the above program will be:

```
    Root element :company
----------------------------

Current Element :staff
Staff id : 1001
First Name : yong
Last Name : mook kim
Nick Name : mkyong
Salary : 100000

Current Element :staff
Staff id : 2001
First Name : low
Last Name : yin fong
Nick Name : fong fong
Salary : 200000
```

You can write a similar code to read the particular column from your xml file. In your xml file the root elemnt is `Workbook`. You need to get the `Worksheet` node and then you can get the required value.