# Java Jframe, Opens several Windows after running it, why?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, user-interface, jframe

here my question , i´m studying IT , and for my work i need to program a server where people can Upload  7-zip files and then let them unzip on the Server

now .. the problem is i need to set default path with xml , after i did that my programm opens 3 windows...

hope someone can help me , because i just want one Window

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class ClientFenster {
    private File selectedFile;

    private JPanel Fenster1;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1;
    private JButton selectPathButton;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JTextArea listSelectedFile;
    private JTable table1;
    private JScrollPane ScrollPane;
    private JPanel JPanelLogo;
    private JComboBox LocalServerBox;
    private JLabel JLabelLogo;
    private JPanel SelectedFilesTest;

    public ClientFenster() {

        BuildServerServerApplicationTests Build = new BuildServerServerApplicationTests();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();// Tabelle

        selectPathButton.addActionListener(new FileChooser());
        File file = new File("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
        file.setWritable(true);// punkt 29 in Requirements

        JLabelLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo3.png")); //Logo
        table1.setModel(model);
        table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);;
        table1.setGridColor(Color.gray);
        table1.setShowGrid(false);

        model.addColumn("Date");
        model.addColumn("Size");
        model.addColumn("Status");
        model.addColumn("Name Zip");
        model.addColumn ("Time");
        model.addColumn("Project Name");
        model.addColumn("User");

        model.addRow(new Object[] {Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(),(file.length()/1024), "Offen" , Build.filename + ".zip", "Zeit" , "Proejkt Name", System.getProperty("user.name")});

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClientFenster");
        frame.setContentPane(Fenster1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void setComboBox(String xmlInput) {
        LocalServerBox.addItem(xmlInput);
    }

    public void setComboBox1(String aDefault) {
       comboBox1.addItem(aDefault);
    }


    // JFileChooser Button "select path"
    private class FileChooser extends Component implements ActionListener {


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            //Windows aussehen
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
            int returnValue = chooser.showDialog(FileChooser.this, "Upload");

                //Wenn auf Upload button gedrückt wird == rückgabewert 0
                if(returnValue == 0){

                    BuildServerServerApplicationTests Build = new BuildServerServerApplicationTests();

                    //"löscht" die extensions und lässt dynamische filenames zu
                    Build.filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                    Build.extension = Build.filename.substring(Build.filename.lastIndexOf("."));
                    Build.filename = Build.filename.substring(0,Build.filename.lastIndexOf("."));
                    try {
                        Build.uploadFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    //Combobox
                    //der Pfad des geöffneten File wird ausgegeben
                    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                        comboBox1.addItem(selectedFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
// Main

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientFenster cF = new ClientFenster();
        XmlFileReader readXml = new XmlFileReader();
        XmlFileReaderPath defaultPath = new XmlFileReaderPath();

    }

}
```

```html
Xml FileReader

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.File;


public class XmlFileReader {
    ClientFenster gB = new ClientFenster();

    public XmlFileReader() {

        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("ClientStartup/ClientStartConfig.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //optional, but recommended
            //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("server");

            String xmlF;
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                gB.setComboBox(eElement.getElementsByTagName("address").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Especially focus on that "minimal" part. Not many people will be willing to review such amounts of code for you.

Comment: ok thx for the advise :) still new here

Comment: You are welcome. And just for the record: I understand that what I am asking for isnt always easy to do. Sometimes, problems simply require debugging work. And sometimes the work that is needed to compile all the information to ask a good question ... actually leads you to the solution already.

Comment: While preparing  mcve, you are very likely to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my analysis, Your problem should be here:

```
ClientFenster gB = new ClientFenster();
```

Notice that you are instancing the Client in the Main application:

```
ClientFenster cF = new ClientFenster();
```

And then, when instantiating XmlFileReader, you are re-instantiating it again.

```
XmlFileReader readXml = new XmlFileReader();
```

I'm also supposing that the third window is because XmlFileReaderPath extends XmlFileReader.

Comment: ah now i see, but what would be the best solution ? when i try to change those , he says that he needs those ... OK got it :D still thx for all :)

Comment: Well, if you want ClientFenster to only have 1 instance, and you need to access that instance from inside XmlFileReader class, then you need to pass it as a constructor parameter.