# What is a proper name for lines of code responsible for fetching data from web txt?

Tags: java, url, dom, inputstream

I need help with dividing these lines of code and putting them into methods:

```
   url = new URL(URL_SOURCE);
   con = url.openConnection();
  is = con.getInputStream();
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("pozycja");
```

I divied it into:

```
 public URLConnection openConnectionOfGivenURL(String givenURL) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(givenURL);
    return url.openConnection();
}
```

I dont know what should I do with the rest. Should I name it with `getDOM` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all except first and last line should be in a method. Don't try to divvy *that* code up further than that. E.g. `Document getXml(URL url)` or maybe name it `downloadXml` if you only intend to use it with HTTP(S) urls.

The main reason for not divvying it up further, is that you should use try-with-resources.

Also, you don't need to normalize a parsed DOM, since [the parser is already creating a normalized DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935335/5221149).

```
Document getXml(URL url) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    try (InputStream is = con.getInputStream()) {
        return dBuilder.parse(is);
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
URL url = new URL(URL_SOURCE);
Document doc = getXml(url);
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("pozycja");
```