# Convert Android Studio strings.xml to Eclipse MessagesBundle_en_US.properties

Tags: java, android, translation, properties-file, resourcebundle

I have a Java game that has a (Android Studio app client) and (Eclipse pc client).  I am working on language translation.  I set up ResourceBundles.properties via Eclipse and strings.xml for Android Studio.  I like the UI of the Android Studio Translations Editor, but need a way to convert it out into Resource Bundles OR use the strings.xml files.  Is there an easy way to convert or load the Android Studio outputs so I can manage one master list of translated strings?  Any free web based approach that allows me to export to .properties and .xml works too.

**Eclipse Java code to use language files**

[image]

```
public static void updateLocale() {
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);
    try{
        File file = new File("res/gamedata");
        URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale, loader);
        //messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res/gamedata/MessagesBundle", currentLocale); //old way - needs to be in classpath
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                theDesktop.repaint(); //TODO:: test this when changing languages
            }
        });
    } catch (MissingResourceException e){
        KisnardOnline.LOGGER.error("Language files missing", e);
        //hardcoded values if you can't open the String lookups
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theDesktop, "Language files missing. Please reload game.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        KisnardOnline.LOGGER.error("Language files missing", e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theDesktop, "Language files missing. Please reload game.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

**Android Studio code to use language files**

public final String getString(@StringRes int resId)
Returns a localized string from the application's package's default string table.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to do this for anyone else with this question:

**Sample Android Studio strings.xml:**

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">Kisnard Online</string>
    <string name="drawable_banner_stacked_kisnard_online_description" translatable="false">Kisnard Online Banner</string>
    <string name="general_file_locks">"Can't open or access necessary game files.  Please ensure you are not modifying any game files."</string>
    <string name="general_success">Success</string>
    <string name="general_confirm">Confirm</string>
    <string name="general_error">Error</string>
</resources>
```

**Java code to read from this syntax:**

```
public static void loadStringsXML() {
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings_de.xml", de_DE_Messages);
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings.xml", en_US_Messages);
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings_es.xml", es_ES_Messages);
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings_fr.xml", fr_FR_Messages);
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings_it.xml", it_IT_Messages);
    loadStringXML("res/gamedata/strings_ko.xml", ko_KR_Messages);
}

public static void loadStringXML(String filename, HashMap<String, String> hashMap) {
    // Instantiate the Factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // optional, but recommended
        // process XML securely, avoid attacks like XML External Entities (XXE)
        dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

        // parse XML file
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));

        // optional, but recommended
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node node = list.item(temp);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                String name = element.getAttribute("name");
                String value = node.getTextContent();
                value = value.replace("\\'", "'"); //Android string file requires single quotes to be escaped
                //System.out.println(name + "=" + value);
                hashMap.put(name, value);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```